# Why does my column value not appear in jQuery datatable export?

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have jquery datatables like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example1').DataTable( {

"fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
            $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
           return nRow;
        },
 "columnDefs": [ {
        "paging": true,
      "lengthChange": false,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": true,
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0
    } ],
 dom: 'lBfrtip',  
buttons: [
    'copyHtml5','excelHtml5','csvHtml5',pdfHtml5']
} );
```

in my local it works well:

[image]

but if I export to pdfhtml5, excelhtml5 and csv html, the column numbering does not appear.

[image]

How to solve that? To show column numbering in export datatables with html5?

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fnRowCallback` is meant to be used for *post processing* (i.e adding additional styles or formatting to the content) and is called *whenever* a row is displayed.

So what you visually see as continuous numbers in column #1 is simply just the output of continuous calls to `fnRowCallback` - the underlying data is never changed, and therefore the data is missing when the table is exported. If you want to manipulate content of the table - so the changes is persistent - you must go through the API.

Among several solutions you can use the `createdRow` callback :

```
createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
  this.api().cell({ row:index, column:0 }).data(index+1)
}
```

`cell().data()` persistently updates the underlying data; or you can take advantage of the `render` method in your `columnDefs` :

```
columnDefs: [{
  targets: 0,
  autoWidth: true,
  searchable: false,
  orderable: false,
  render: function(data, type, row, info) {
     return parseInt(info.row)+1;
  }   
}]
```